# Can I tell Xcode 5 to use .cc instead of .cpp for C++ files?

Tags: xcode5

For irrational nostalgic reasons, I like `.cc`, not `.cpp`. So I manually change every C++ file that  Xcode creates. Is there a way to change the template somewhere?

Comment: Not without modifying the template, which is possible.  Otherwise manually changing the extension is the only way.

Comment: Okay, found the templates under /Applications/Xcode.app/. That works. It probably gets wiped out by an update, but it's good enough for me.

Comment: NO!  You need to install them in `~/Library/...` somewhere....